# How to control the default distance between ticks of the Y axis?

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, matlab-figure

Here is a simple MATLAB code. How to control the default distance between ticks of the Y axis? I want to make it smaller to fit in my paper.  Hint: I update the post with 2 picture that shows what I mean (they are the same but the distance between the y axis ticks is smaller in one picture that the other.

[image]

```
x = linspace(-10,10,200); 
y = sin(4*x)./exp(x); 
plot(x,y)
xlim([0 10])
ylim([-0.4 0.8])
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with making the distance between ticks smaller to fit your paper? Does changing this distance somehow imply that the plot will be smaller? Do you want to reduce the length of the y axis? Something similar to what you get when you drag the corner of the figure window to make it smaller?

Comment: I update the post  with  2 picture that shows what I mean( they are the same but the distance between the y axis ticks is smaller in one picture that the other. I mean to change the default distance between the ticks

Comment: Awesome! This clarifies a lot what you mean by distance between ticks.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the tick by using the gca object of the plot. Here is an example for xtick. Change `'xtick'` to `'ytick'`:

```
plot(x,y);
set(gca, 'xtick', [-10:2:10]);
```

Comment: I want to control the length between xticks

Comment: This is the closest that you can get in my experience. The larger the step size the fewer number of ticks between grid points, which will make it more readable. You can resize your graph by clicking on it and stretching it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the x-axis tick labels with new labels, then you can change the values of the labels as follows:

```
% specify the ticks first where you want to change
xticks([0 2 4 6 8])
% change the corresponding labels to the required ones
xticklabels({'-1', '-2', '-3', '-4', '-5'})
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the height of the graph, maintaining the number and values of the tick marks, which makes the distance between tick marks smaller.

To do so, set the figure window’s `'Position'` property (this is equivalent to dragging the edges of the window to make the figure smaller), and setting the locations of the tick marks manually to prevent MATLAB from reducing their number. For example:

```
h = gcf; % figure handle
a = gca; % axes handle
ticks = get(a,'YTick');
pos = get(h,'Position');
pos(4) = pos(4) * 0.75; # reduce the size
set(h,'Position',pos);
set(a,'YTick',ticks)
```

You should also note the PaperPosition, PaperSize and other Paper... properties of the figure, as they are used when printing (also to file). You might want to manually set those properties before creating a PDF or EPS from the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Here is even a simpler way then what [@Cris suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964021/2627163):

```
ax = axes;
ax.YTickMode = 'manual';
ax.Position(4) = ax.Position(4)*0.75;
```

by setting the `YTickMode` to manual you prevent Matlab from updating the ticks upon resizing of the axes. Then you change the hight of the axes by setting the `position` property directly.